# WebRTC IP leak in 2021

Tags: ip, webrtc

it's been a while since WebRTC was seen as a possible opportunity for IP leak when using a VPN.

We're in 2021 today and I was wondering if there have been some improvements with this protocol in term of security.

I mean, Edge is currently WebRTC enabled by default, whereas Firefox is WebRTC disabled.

So I tried a few websites testing for WebRTC IP leak and noticed Edge has no issue and keeps my own public IP private. All tests were unable to find my real IP.

So here I am, wondering if WebRTC has become safe and can be kept enabled in Edge with no worries. Of course I need WebRTC occasionally otherwise I would certainly keep the beast disabled.

Comment: Nothing has changed. See also a current article from a VPN provider about this topic - https://nordvpn.com/blog/webrtc/

Comment: Instead of posting a new question which duplicates other older questions, the older questions' answers should be updated or added to so there is not a fracturing of the core knowledge

Comment: @steffenUllrich Then why can't I find a test website than can find my real IP? All those tests are BS?

Comment: @schroeder I'm sorry but I disagree, the 3 links above have no answer to my questions. I had read them before posting and I see nothing that helps. The deal here is to explain why no test can find my real IP despite WebRTC being enabled.

Comment: So, you really just want to know why your tests fail in Edge? That's different from your stated question. Your question about WebRTC security, in general, is covered by the duplicates. If you want to know why your tests fail, then you need to explain the tests, how you ran them, what you expected the results to be and what the results were. All my WebRTC IP leak tests showed a leak on Edge.